# d3.js - why would calling d3.zoom() from the element that is being modified fail to zoom?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Hi Following is the working code. It zooms whatever contents that are within `canvas` / `g` element

```
  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .call(d3.zoom()
              .scaleExtent([1 / 2, 4])
              .on("zoom", zoomed));
  
  const canvas = svg.append("g");
              
  function zoomed() {
    canvas.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
  }
```

Following is the code that is not work.

```
  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);
  
  const canvas = svg.append("g")
                    .call(d3.zoom()
                            .scaleExtent([1 / 2, 4])
                            .on("zoom", zoomed));
              
  function zoomed() {
    canvas.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
  }
```

Why does the second example fail to zoom at all compare to the first example? Since `.on("zoom", zoomed)` is working on canvas, I was thinking calling it on canvas g element would work.

Comment: What exactly *does not work*?  Do you see any errors or does it not work properly?

Comment: It was definitely unclear. My apology. Second example fails to zoom the same way first example would even though contents of fucntion `zoomed` are same.